# Qualify a generic type in typescript

Tags: typescript

Given a function:

```
export const Fn = <T>(arg: T) => ({...});
```

I would like to write arrive a specialized Fn restricted to specific type. But something like the following does not work:

```
export const SpecializedFn = Fn<MyInterface>;
```

What is the correct syntax for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function, that returns a generic function.

```
function functionFactory<T>() {
    let func = (a: T) => console.log(a); 
    return func;
} 

export const SpecializedFn = functionFactory<number>();
```

In this case `SpecializedFn` now is a function which accepts a number.